# Why doesn't negative values for the second index in a jagged array work in Python?

Tags: python, jagged-arrays

For example, if I have the following (data from Project Euler):

```
s = [[75],
     [95, 64],
     [17, 47, 82],
     [18, 35, 87, 10],
     [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
     [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
     [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
     [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
     [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
     [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
     [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
     [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
     [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
     [63, 66, 4, 68,89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
     [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
```

Why does `s[1:][:-1]` give me the same thing as `s[1:]` instead of (what I want) `[s[i][:-1] for i in range(1,len(s))]`. In other words, why does Python ignore my second index?

Comment: It shouldn't give you the same thing as `s[1:]`...  `s[1:][:-1]` gives a newly-constructed list containing all of the elements of `s` from `[95, 64]` to `[63, 66, 4, 68,89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],`.  In other words: `[[95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], ..., [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31]]`.  If you really have a problem with it, is there a reason why you don't want to use the list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't have 2-dimensional lists, it has lists of lists. I think the first [1:] gives everything but the first contained list, and the second [:-1] takes that result and removes the last contained list.

What you want is:

```
[r[:-1] for r in s[1:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misdescribing the results: `s[1:][:-1]` is definitely **not** the same as `s[:1]`, as you erroneously say -- it is, rather, the same as `s[1:-1]`.  Check it out!

This must necessarily hold true of **any** list `s`, no matter what its contents may be (other lists, dicts, strings, floats, unicorns, ...): `s[1:]` means "all but the first", then `[:-1]` means "all but the last", so obviously their combined effects are the same as `[1:-1]` which means "all but the first and last".  The indexing-like syntax with a colon in the brackets is also known as *slicing*, and when applied to a list (of whatevers) it returns another (typically shorter) list (also of whatevers).

Thinking of `s` as a "jagged array" rather than what it actually **is** (just a list, whose items happen to also be lists -- but the type of some or all of the items obviously can't and shouldn't affect the semantics of operations *on the list itself*, like slicing) may be what's throwing you off; perhaps because, if the first indexing is actually an indexing and not a slicing, its results is an *item* of the original list -- a "whatever" (a list of ints in your case), not a list of whatevers.  So if you then apply a further indexing or slicing you're doing that on one of the original sublists -- a very different matter.

@Mark's answer has already shown the canonical list-comprehension solution to do what you actually want.  I think that other approaches, if you have matlab code and want the Python equivalent, might include [OMPC](http://ompc.juricap.com/) (but I haven't tried that myself).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice the difference in the results. Thank you for your explanation. :)